# Clear terminated EC2 instances from AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using Terraform to provision some infrastructure, but the debugging process causes a lot of terminated instances (destroy/recreate). When listing instances in the AWS console, all terminated instances are still listed. Is there a way to clear them? This is causing a lot of clutter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove the clutter by adding a search filter. Type `Instance State : !Terminated` in the search filter bar at the top. (note the spaces around `:`)

Comment: Is there a more permanent way? I'd like for other developers to not have to add a filter.

Comment: It seems like there isn't any way. It might help that the filter goes into the dashboard URL, because you can share that link with other developers.

Comment: They will also vanish by themselves after about 20 minutes

Comment: Possible dupe of http://serverfault.com/questions/393417/delete-amazon-ec2-terminated-instance

Comment: Actually, they disappear after 60 minutes. If you don't want to use a filter, you could write a Greasemonkey script to disappear them for you!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein is this documented anywhere?

Comment: No, not documented. I timed it one day.

Comment: $('span').filter(function() { return ($(this).text() === 'terminated') }).parents('tr').hide();

Answer (score 3):

They'll disappear after some time (~30 mins)

Answer (score 1):

Another (likely less popular) answer: Stop using the console. It's just a thin layer on the Amazon APIs. Write small scripts (using the AWS CLI or Boto) or a small website that will query AWS and show your infrastructure the way you want to see it.

Comment: I think I like the way you think.

Answer (score 0):

According to official documentation it will be remove automatically after some time.
you can check here 
[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html](http://Terminate%20Aws%20Instance)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)